# How to: Get Report Definition using SSRS RESTful API?

Tags: rest, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have been working with the RESTful SSRS endpoint documentation at https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0 and It states that I can retrieve the Report defintiion for my reports, however I cannot find any of the endpoints to do such?

**From Microsoft docs:**

> The REST API can also be used to provide more advanced functionality,
>   such as:
>
> - Navigate the folder hierarchy Discover the contents of a folder
> - Download a report definition
> - Modify default report parameters Change
> - or execute a refresh plan A whole lot more
>
> The REST API is a RESTful successor to the legacy SOAP API.

Maybe I am missing something?

I am able to get the Parameter Definitions, the report by ID,

however passing in any parameters such as

```
https://{myreportserver}/reports/api/v2.0/reports({id})?paramter1=somevalue
```

does not return any definition. I am trying to get a definition return so maybe I can render the report on a web application (or at minimum provide a pdf download of the report?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the game, but in case anyone else is looking for this answer, use this URL:

```
https://{myreportserver}/reports/api/v2.0/reports({id})?Content/$value
```